# How to make order by specific value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanna select data from table with ordering where first I'll get values with specific value.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```sql
SELECT name FROM test ORDER BY id ='d189463e-52dc-40e5-adf7-eddce74cf05e';
```

Comment: "but it didn't work" Did you get an error (if so, which one)?  Why do you think it "did not work" (please describe what you wanted to receive, but did not get) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a case expression  This allows you to define whatever "ordering" you want for the IDs

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 'd189463e-52dc-40e5-adf7-eddce74cf05e' THEN 1 
              WHEN ID = ... ELSE ... END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write

```
ORDER BY id <> 'd189463e-52dc-40e5-adf7-eddce74cf05e'
```

or

```
ORDER BY id = 'd189463e-52dc-40e5-adf7-eddce74cf05e' DESC
```

because `FALSE < TRUE`.